# Core Bluetooth Characteristic Notification Not Working

Tags: ios7, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am trying to write a BTLE monitoring app that receives notifications. I have built both the central app and a mock peripheral app using Core Bluetooth (on iOS 7.1). My central can connect fine to the peripheral, which advertises a service that has 2 `CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify` characteristics. But here is what happens once the central discovers the characteristics (removing non-essential code for clarity).

**PD = CBPeripheralDelegate in central**

**PMD = CBPeripheralManagerDelegate in peripheral**

PD callback invoked

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error
{
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics)
    {
        [peripheral setNotifyValue:YES forCharacteristic:characteristic];
    }
}
```

PMD callback invoked twice for the 2 characteristics

```
- (void)peripheralManager:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral central:(CBCentral *)central didSubscribeToCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic
{
    if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:FILTER_GENUINE_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]])
    {
        BOOL genuineSent = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:genuineValue
                                                     forCharacteristic:self.filterGenuineCharacteristic
                                                  onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
    }
    else if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:FILTER_LOADING_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]])
    {
        BOOL loadingSent = [self.peripheralManager updateValue:loadingValue
                                                     forCharacteristic:self.filterLoadingCharacteristic
                                                  onSubscribedCentrals:nil];
    }
}
```

Note: The first time this method is invoked the return from `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:` is `YES`. The second time the return is always `NO`.

PD callback invoked twice for the 2 characteristics

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

Note: `characteristic.isNotifying` is always `YES`.

**But that¹s it, no other callback methods are invoked!**

PMD callback `peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:` is never called for the `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:` call that returned `NO`

```
- (void)peripheralManagerIsReadyToUpdateSubscribers:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
```

PD callback `peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:` is never called for the `updateValue:forCharacteristic:onSubscribedCentrals:` call that returned `YES`

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error
```

I have been testing these apps on an iPad Air and iPhone 5s, both running iOS 7.1.

**Any idea why the notification is never invoked?**

Comment: I have the same issue on iOS 8.1.3 with iPhone 6. I'm calling updateValue for notified, subscribed characteristics. However, after the first call to updateValue fails there is no ReadyToUpdateSubscribers callback.